# How to force Squid cache video/f4f mime-type

Tags: caching, proxy, video-streaming, squid

I have hds stream server based on flussonic/erlyvideo + squid proxy cache (local network).
I need to make squid cache video flow fragments.
Squid can cache video from inventos.ru (mime-type fragment header text/plain), but can't cache from my server: video/f4f fragments mime-type.

How to make squid cache video/f4f fragments.

Squid Config:

```
acl all src all
acl mynet src 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0

acl SSL_ports port 443          # https
acl SSL_ports port 563          # snews
acl SSL_ports port 873          # rsync
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 8080        # stream hds
acl Safe_ports port 1935        # rtmp
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl Safe_ports port 631         # cups
acl Safe_ports port 873         # rsync
acl Safe_ports port 901         # SWAT
acl purge method PURGE
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access allow all
http_access allow mynet

http_port 3128

acl yammervideo dstdomain *.yammer.com
acl inventos dstdomain inventos.ru
acl targetvideodomain dstdomain v.tst.com
#cache allow video
#cache allow yammervideo
cache allow inventos
cache allow targetvideodomain
cache allow all
#We recommend you to use at least the following line.
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?


access_log /var/log/squid/access.log squid
cache_dir ufs /var/squidcache 500 16 256

#Suggested default:
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$       0       20%     2880
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320


# Don't upgrade ShoutCast responses to HTTP
acl shoutcast rep_header X-HTTP09-First-Line ^ICY.[0-9]
upgrade_http0.9 deny shoutcast


acl apache rep_header Server ^Apache
broken_vary_encoding allow apache

#  TAG: extension_methods
#       Squid only knows about standardized HTTP request methods.
#       You can add up to 20 additional "extension" methods here.
extension_methods REPORT MERGE MKACTIVITY CHECKOUT


hosts_file /etc/hosts


# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
```

Squid access log (short):

```
1358797512.502    939 85.21.245.191 TCP_MISS/200 918268 GET http://v.tst.com/ren/mm1.mp4/hds/tracks-1,2/Seg1-Frag9 - DIRECT/91.218.230.83 video/f4f
1358797516.090    936 85.21.245.191 TCP_MISS/200 571690 GET http://v.tst.com/ren/mm1.mp4/hds/tracks-1,2/Seg1-Frag10 - DIRECT/91.218.230.83 video/f4f
```

Store log:

```
1358797618.493 RELEASE -1 FFFFFFFF D16DC1B649CD3523AC0BC86E7C8ECB45  200 1358797616        -1        -1 video/f4f 1737948/1737948 GET http://v.tst.com/ren/mm1.mp4/hds/tracks-1,2/Seg1-Frag28
1358797623.862 RELEASE -1 FFFFFFFF 284EB9F58EF52724EF68378D237F0594  200 1358797622        -1        -1 video/f4f 1578659/1578659 GET http://v.tst.com/ren/mm1.mp4/hds/tracks-1,2/Seg1-Frag29
```

Comment: please answer you own question since you have an answer.